# How are harmless but potentially painful or undesirable scenes shot in medical TV shows?

Tags: production

I am using House MD as an example, but this is not specific to that show.

There are scenes where patients get injected something, or they have blood taken, or they get a small cut when operated. Another example might be when they intubate a patient.

I don't know if any of this might be potentially harmful, but I think the cost of actually doing it might be lower than faking it with CGI.

Note that, as I'm saying in the title, I'm talking about *harmless* scenes, not scenes impossible to film live, like surgery.

Comment: Consider 'the cost of actually doing it' vs., "Cut there. Reset. Going again" What happens on take two?? That's before you consider who would volunteer in the first place. They are usually physical effects not CGI, but I don't have sufficient link refs to make this an answer.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't! But on the other hand, I've fainted multiple times at my blood tests, so I was curious to see if it was just me or if it was something reasonable :) Anyway, good point, the small cut is out, but something like the intubation might not be.

Comment: I had already seen that question while researching for this answer. The scope is different, as that question focuses on things that don't have the option of being done for real.

Comment: I guess it is a combination of tricks and props. Like in Game of Thrones with the throat slitting scenes, they use fluid packets under a fake skin that is used to simulate the cutting. 
I cannot confirm this with a proof, but they can also operate on props for operating scenes and shoot the same scene with a person who is prominent in the episode and then editing tricks do the rest to show that a person is being operated on. These are the things they can do, if they do not use CGI.

Comment: On top of Tetsujin's point about multiple takes, there's also the small detail that the people administering these shots or intubating the patient are *not actually doctors*.  These actors don't know how to do it properly any more than you would.  You know those fake knives that fold in on themselves when you push the blade?  They use syringes and intubating props with a similar collapsing feature so it doesn't actually go in, or they film from an angle that makes it look like it's going in when it isn't really.